# Picking the right exception handling in scala

Tags: scala, exception, coding-style

I'm new to Scala, being slightly confused at the various ways to handle exceptions and looking for best-practice advice on the topic. I'm writing a simple method to retrieve a Customer using an existing blocking SDK. The possible outcomes are:

1. Customer is found
2. Customer is not found (comes back as a NotFoundException from the SDK)
3. Error while talking to remote server (SDK throws some other exception)

So I want my method to have a return type `Future[Option[Customer]]`, and return for each case above:

1. Successful Future: Some(customer)
2. Successful Future: None
3. Failed Future

Here is what I wrote using try/catch:

```
private def findCustomer(userId: Long): Future[Option[Customer]] = future {
  try {
    Some(gateway.find(userId))
  } catch {
    case _: NotFoundException => None
  }
}
```

This works fine and seems clean to me, but doesn't seem to be really the "Scala way" to do it - I've been told to avoid using try/catch. So I've been looking for a way to rewrite it using a `Try` instead.

Here are 2 variants that (I think) behave exactly the same, using a `Try`.

Variant A:

```
private def findCustomer(userId: Long): Future[Option[Customer]] = future {
  Try(
    Some(gateway.find(userId))
  ).recover {
    case _: NotFoundException => None
  }.get
}
```

Variant B:

```
private def findCustomer(userId: Long): Future[Option[Customer]] = future {
  Try(
    Some(gateway.find(userId))
  ).recover {
    case _: NotFoundException => None
  }
} flatMap {
  case Success(s) => Future.successful(s)
  case Failure(f) => Future.failed(f)
}
```

I'm not a huge fan of A (even though it's more concise than B) since the `.get` seems a bit treacherous. B is definitely the most explicit but mapping the `Try` cases to corresponding `Future` outcomes seems boring.

How would an experienced Scala programmer write this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your initial version using `try/catch` is perfectly fine, because it's a wrapper around an existing SDK.

Alternatively, you can use the `recover` method on `Future`:

```
def findCustomer(userId: Long): Future[Option[Customer]] =
  Future(Option(gateway.find(userId))).recover {
    case e: NotFoundException => None
  }
```

Comment: Beautiful! I think `Future { ... } recover { ... }` is exactly what I was looking for, concise, expressive and idiomatic. Thanks!

Comment: This is good, but you should change the Some => Option to protect against Some(null).

Comment: @TaylorLeese you're right. I used `Some` because I knew that the method would throw when the user does not exist, but it doesn't hurt to use `Option`.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to avoid chaining Try and Future. In a sense, a future is an asynchronous Try.

You could use Future[Customer] directly and consider NotFoundException as something to recover from rather than a None value. Normally, you would chain operation on the future itself, with no need to deal with the failure cases (by mapping it, etc). It all depends on how you are going to use it (how your logic branches when the future is completed). In other words, maybe it seems convoluted to you because it is, and you are forcing it to be by forcing the Future[Option[Customer]] return type.

The ability to do chain multiple operations and carry on with computing if and only if all if going all right is the nice Scala feature here (especially on for comprehensions, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for:

```
Future.fromTry(myTry)
```

So for your example you might do:

```
Future.fromTry {
    Try(Some(gateway.find(userId))).recover {
        case _: NotFoundException => None
    }
}
```

To only catch the `NotFoundException`, as in your solution.  The only problem here is that the method won't be executed asynchronously.  If that is necessary, consider using `Future.recover`, as suggested by Ionut.

Another idiomatic option worth mentioning here is to use `Either[F, S]`, where `S` is the type of the successful return, and `F` can hold the errors (which you might want to propagate).  So you could use `Either[ Exception, Option[String]]` or `Either[String, Option[String]]` where the first `String` is an error message.

Comment: The problem with this approach (using `Future.fromTry`) is that the computation isn't done asynchronously. The created `Future` is already completed.

Comment: Also, the convention for `Either[A, B]` is to have `A` represent the failure and `B` the success. So `Either[F, S]`.

Comment: The fact that there *is* an argument about it makes me think I shouldn't use Either. I'd rather rely on a language built in (like `Try` which already allows to return either a Success or a Failure) than on a convention that people don't seem to agree on :)
Thanks for the pointer though!

Comment: That's reasonable, but I just want to note that I actually agree with Ionut and have since edited my post.  I think the convention is pretty well accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ready to adopt some [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz). disjunction from scalaz is very useful and natural in handling erronous scenarios. It's like scala `Either` but scalaz disjunction `\/` is right biased. you'll have success value  on the right and exception on left. wrapping your code block with `\/.fromTryCatch` returns exception on the left side of disjunction. right will always have success value. mapping over disjunction is easiser than Scala Either since disjunction is right biased and easily gives you value from right.

```
import scalaz.\/

private def findCustomer(userId: Long): Future[\/[Throwable,Option[Customer]] ]= future {
  \/.fromTryCatch {
    Some(gateway.find(userId))

  }
}
```